# Remove some traffic tracked in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Accidentally,I inserted the Tracking-ID of a website that wasn't the right one. That is, I have two domains and for a few days both domains have had the same Tracking-ID. Now I can see traffic on pages from the wrong domain. How can I remove that traffic?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove that particular acquired traffic.

However, you can look at the data using a segment that excludes unwanted traffic.

Comment: Based in this very broad answer, what I did was, I created a custom segment in GAU with "Page Title" contains [my website name]. Because every page title shows the website name, the traffic in the other website is not counted. This segmente is also available in DataStudio so I used it there too.